# Home folder encrypted, hacker has physical access - safe to ssh to it?

Tags: networking, ssh, encryption, home-directory

A computer runs Ubuntu with home folder encryption. It is switched on but not logged in. Another computer connects to it over SSH, allowing browsing of the home folder through the terminal. Can a hacker with physical access now read the home folder data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `root` user has full access to any encrypted home folders while those users are logged in. Someone with physical access to the computer can modify the kernel to give themselves root access and access the files that way.

The SSH server can see any passwords entered, and the SSH server executable can be modified by someone with physical access to provide the password to them.

Comment: Logged in != home folder accessible.

Comment: In general, it does, especially with the normal setup provided by Ubuntu. The question was about what could happen, and this could happen. The question wasn't about something that will work under any possible circumstances.

Comment: It only happens when the user logs in locally. OP is asking about them logging in remotely.

Comment: I've just verified this myself. Logging in via SSH with a password does decrypt the home folder automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I am just guessing but I would say no because first the hacker has to get passed the os security like your password on you computer and to do that they would need to eather know the password or atempt to crack the password to do that I would say they would need to shut the computer down and load a os from a usb so if they know the password it dosnt matter and you would not be able to ssh if they loaded a os from usb.

As for you reading your files while you are using ssh and reading files, based on [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124235/where-are-decrypted-files-stored-during-runtime) the home folder is never fully decrypted and the decypted data is never stored on the hard drive only in the RAM, a hacker might be able to get something from the ram but it would not be your whole home folder and I think to do it they would need to shut your computer down [(this is what i am referring to)](http://www.zdnet.com/article/cryogenically-frozen-ram-bypasses-all-disk-encryption-methods/) to do it and I dont think it would be to easy to read a raw memory dump.

so I dont think I would be to worred if they have access to your computer then there are probably easyer ways of getting the information stored on the hard drive.

**Update**

With the whole hard drive being decrypted when you login over ssh if the hacker could get passed os security then by loging in you would be giving the hacker access to your files.

Comment: But the home folder is effectively fully decrypted while the user is logged in. The `root` user can read any files, even those not being accessed by the user. This can be verified by logging in as a user with an encrypted home directory, then logging in separately (perhaps on a second console) as another user, using `sudo -i`, then going to look at the content of the first user's files.

Comment: thank you I did not realise that while the home folder was mounted the whole folder was decrypted. so would I be correct in saying that while you are loged in it would be as if your files are not encrypted at all untill you logout

Comment: Yes, that's the case, though, like normal, permissions can still keep other users (other than `root`) from using or seeing the files.

Answer (score -1):

A skilled person with physical access to the machine can install a keylogger (physical device) and access your home folder after you log in locally on that machine, again. In general: A skilled person with physical access to your machine ... what do you mean by "my machine"? It's not your machine any more.

However, what you're probably more interested in: Your home folder doesn't become accessible when you log in via SSH.

You probably should make sure that you can log in at all because in the default configuration, the authorized public keys are stored in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` which of course can't be read if your home folder isn't accessible at the time of the login attempt. If you change the configuration, you can log in via public key authentication but your home folder doesn't become accessible because your system really doesn't know your password.

If you log in via password (which you shouldn't!), you tell your system your password but afaik, your home folder still doesn't become accessible. For this to happen, you have to run:

```
ecryptfs-mount-private
```

If it does automatically become accessible, you of course don't have to run this command.

So let's assume you managed to log in and your home folder is accessible.

If we exclude very advanced abilities of the attacker, they still can't access your home folder unless they can log into the machine using some account on it.

If we don't exclude the attacker's abilities being very advanced, they can for example get your data and even your encryption key via a [cold boot attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_boot_attack). Different attacks are possible but significantly less bad-ass (like shutting your sever down and booting an operating system which in turn boots your server's usual operating system but maintains full control over your server and can read the RAM as it wished; alternatively the attacker could change parts of your operating system to send data back to them when you make your home folder accessible the next time).

However, the attacker just installing a keylogger is way more likely then any advanced attack being carried out.

Comment: This is incorrect. Logging in via password, through the graphical interface or through SSH, does unencrypt the home directory automatically.

Comment: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1332820

Comment: Mentioning a place where a bug of some sort occurred or someone changed their password in a way that didn't update ecryptfs doesn't tell what happens by default. I've verified it myself. The question here even verifies it: "Another computer connects to it over SSH, **allowing browsing of the home folder through the terminal.**" Your answer isn't answering the question posed.

Comment: I changed my answer in case I'm wrong.